# Is ECN (Explicit Congestion Notification) turned on by default on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: networking, tcp, windows-server-2012, netsh

In a company network I noticed that all examined Windows Server 2012 machines had [ECN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification#Microsoft_Windows) turned on:

```
> netsh interface tcp show global

TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
```

...

```
ECN Capability                      : enabled
```

Is it turned on by default on Windows Server 2012? On all older Windows systems I saw it turned off by default which is confirmed in the Wikipedia article.<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification#Microsoft_Windows)</sup> I could not find the information about Windows Server 2012 anywhere.

Though the [ECN RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3168) was published in 2001 there are still many devices and internet services which do not work correctly with ECN. Such a change in Windows would be somewhat courageous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ECN (which is used by DCTCP) is enabled by default in Server 2012.

Oh, and here's the article about it, exclusively for Server 2012. It's pretty neat:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997028.aspx

Here's a very nice PDF on the subject from Microsoft Research:
http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/121386/dctcp-public.pdf

Comment: Answer is useful, but perhaps a misleading: ECN (2001) predates DCTCP (2010). Its a flag in the IP packet which provides a means for devices on a route to say "I'm busy - slow down before I stop dropping packets". DCTCP is explicitly intended for use on small (LAN sized) busy networks where the ratio of ECN flagged / non-ECN flagged packets informs nodes about available network capacity. i.e. ECN behaves differently for DCTCP compared with non-DCTCP devices.